# TypeError: dynamodb.DocumentClient is not a function

Tags: visual-studio-2015, aws-lambda, typeerror

I'm using MS VS 2015 to develop AWS lambda node.js function. I always got error 
"**TypeError: XXX is not a function**" whatever AWS function I called. for example 
code is

```
var AWS     = require('aws-sdk');    
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

I got error:

```
TypeError: dynamodb.DocumentClient is not a function
```

if I comment this line and write

```
context.succeed();
```

I got error:

```
TypeError: context.succeed is not a function
```

Anyone know what is the issue

Comment: Not enough infornation. Please put the snippet of the code where you are getting the error. And also the screenshot of error. `XXX` is not a terminology used! : FYI.

Comment: Update it to be more readable :)